# Add character in a link

Tags: python

I want to add an character to a link.
The link is `C:\Users\user\Documents\test.csv` I want to add `C:\Users\user\Documents\test_new.csv`.
So you can see I added the **_new** to the filename.

Should I extract the name with `Path(path).name)` and then with Regex? What is the best option for do that?

Comment: Are looking to append _new to many filename links? There is not much information in your question. You just renamed the file link, which you can do like this,

`import os
os.rename(r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\test.txt',r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\test_new.txt')`

Comment: @AbrarAhmed he didn't said "rename" he said "add" to the path, by the way nice solution to rename the file :-)

Comment: You could use `os.path.splitext`, with or without `os.path.dirname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you want to "add" _new and not rename here is your solution and it is tiny just 2 lines of code apart from the varaible and the result, this is solution might be complex because i have compressed the  code to take less memory and do the work fast, you could also change the keyword and the extension from the `OUTPUT FUNCTION` arguments

```py
PATH = "C:\\User\\Folder\\file.csv"

def new_name(path, ext="csv", keyword="_new"):
    print('\\'.join(path.split("\\")[:-1])+"\\"+path.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0] + keyword + "." + ext)

new_name(PATH)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module:

```
path = r"C:\User\Folder\file.csv"
root, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
new_path = f'{root}_new{ext}'
```

And here's one using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
path = pathlib.Path(r"C:\User\Folder\file.csv")
new_path = str(path.with_stem(path.stem + '_new'))
```

Comment: I fixed a error of yours in the os section in the new_path var you put a dot after _new i removed it because  it results in two dots line test_new..csv

Comment: No Problem, have a nice day coding @0x5453!

Comment: Thank you very much! :)